# How to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$ ？

Tags: calculus

If we know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)<0$, can we show $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x)=0$?

Comment: No, we can't. $f'$ may be close to $0$ most of the time, but have bumps occasionally.

Comment: I am really curious about an example :D

Comment: @Martingalo Define $f$ to be $1/2-\sum_{i=1}^n (1/3)^i$ on $(n,n+1]$. Then  tilt the flat parts slightly and smooth it out appropriately.

Comment: But then $f$ is a piecewise constant function and the derivative is not well-defined at the discontiunity points, so condition $f'(x)<0$ would not be fulfilled. If we smooth it out, we then get a decreasing function and hence $f'(x)<0$ and I'm afraid we will get $\lim_n f'(x)=0$.

Comment: @Martingalo I think my latest example should work

Answer (score 3):

We cannot.  The following construction follows Daniel's idea.

**Counterexample:**

Define 
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 - |x| & -1 \leq x \leq 1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) = 1$.  Define the function
$$
\phi(t) = 1/t^2 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty g(2^k(t-2k))
$$
Noting that $\phi$ is continuous, strictly positive, and $\int_1^\infty \phi(t)dt=2$.  It follows that the function
$$
f(x) = 2 - \int_1^x \phi(t)\,dt
$$
Is a continuously differentiable function on $[1,\infty)$ such that $f(x) \to 0$ but $f'(x) \not \to 0$.

Comment: But the assumption $f'(x)<0$ does not seem to be fulfilled?

Comment: I might be lured by wrong intuition but it seems quite true. let's think about it :)

Comment: My mistake.  Thank you

Comment: This should do the job

Comment: Is function $\phi$ well-written? should $x$ be a $t$? and $2^{k}$ or $2k$ a $2^{-k}$? Cause for big values of $k$ then $2^k (x-2k)$ is outside $(-1,1)$ and hence $g=0$. In any case the derivative is $-\phi (x)$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus) and to me $\lim_{x\to \infty} \phi(x) = 0$. Were am I wrong?

Comment: @Martingalo the $x$ should be a $t$, but everything else is as it should be. Note that for any $t_0$, there is always a $t>t_0$ such that $2^k(t - 2k) \in [-1,1]$, from which we conclude that $\phi(t) \not \to 0$.

Comment: Moreover, $f$ seems to have spikes and in such a case $f'(x)\not <0$ for all $x$. I really think that if $f\in C^1$ With $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $f'(x) <0$ for all $x$ in the domain then $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)=0$ and I have the feeling that it could be proved by reductio ad absurdum.

Comment: Indeed, f has spikes precisely at the points $t_0$ where $|2^k (t_0-2k)|=1$ and $t_0=2k$.

Comment: I think your example is completely correct. Great job! We try to think more about it: If we also know that $f'(x)$ is differentiable, can we prove this result?

Comment: @Martingalo there is no point $t_0\in[1,\infty)$ for which $f'(t_0)\geq 0$.  Do not confuse $-\phi'$ with $f'$. The "spikes" you point out are points at which $f'(x)$ decreases and then increases, never peaking above $0$.

Comment: @user128351 saying $f'$ is differentiable won't help; we can always make $g$ a $C^\infty$ function with compact support.  On the other hand, we might be able to say something if $f'$ is bounded.

Comment: What is the contribution of $1/t^2$ in function $\phi$? could we exclude it?

Comment: That allows $\phi(t)>0$ for all $t$.  Otherwise, we would have $\phi(t) = 0$ periodically, and thus $f'(x) \leq 0$ rather than $f'(x) < 0$ which is desired

Comment: Sure. Yes, very good example. I would still like to see how this looks like, I think this was very counterintuitive. Good thanks a lot!